# Unable to access html elements on jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a javascript (hello.js) during page load in a Quickbase application. On clicking the "Add" button on the page the hello.js is called, which opens a jquery dialog. The dialog has a progress bar and it reaches 100% after a database query in the background has found all the rows required to populate a dropdown on this dialog.

This seems to work perfectly when I click the "Add" button for the first time. However, when I click the "Add" button for the second time (after closing the dialog first time), 1) the dialog opens, 
2) the html elements (i.e. the progress bar and finalMessage) also get displayed.

However, none of the elements can be accessed using jquery functions. I am not able to change any of the values.

```
Here is the code of the hello.js : 

var $dialog;
var arr_stars = new Array(); 
var al=0;

$(function(){
var current_url = document.location.href;
var message  = '<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:290px;">     
</progress>';

message =  message + '<span id="status"> </span> <h4 id="finalMessage">Please wait... </h4>';

message = message + '<label for="lbl_select" id="lbl_select" hidden>STAR#</label>      
<select name="dd_starlist" id="dd_starlist" disabled hidden></select>';

$dialog = $('<div></div>')
.html(message)
.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Add a STAR',
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Add": function() { }           
         },
    close: function() {   
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         }
       });

$dialog.dialog('open');
progressBarSim(al); 
update_dropdown();  
})();

function progressBarSim(al) {    
 var x = document.getElementById("dd_starlist");
 var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
 var status = document.getElementById('status');
 status.innerHTML = al+"%";
 bar.value = al;
 al++;

    if(al == 98){
        status.innerHTML = "97%";
        al=97;
        bar.value = 97;
    }

    var sim = setTimeout("progressBarSim("+al+")",500);

    if(x.disabled == false){
    status.innerHTML = "100%";
    bar.value = 100;
    clearTimeout(sim);
    al=100;
    }   

 }

function update_dropdown()
{
var timestamp =  new Date().getTime();
var url1 =  'XYZ' + timestamp; var i=0;
var x = document.getElementById("dd_starlist");

$.get(url1,function(xml){ 

    $("record",xml).each(function() {              
    arr_stars[i]= $(this).find('transaction_number').text();   
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = $(this).find('transaction_number').text();   
    x.add(option);
    i++;    
    });

 x.disabled = false;
 var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
 finalMessage.innerHTML = "Select a STAR and click Add.";
 $("#lbl_select").show();
 $("#dd_starlist").show();  
 });

}
```

Comment: Have you loaded the jQuery properly (Before you start using the function of hello.js)?

Comment: @ChristosPaisios: yes. I am using this within quickbase application. jquery is loaded properly.

Comment: Could you please open the developer tools in chrome (pressing F12) and go to the tab named Console. There might be some errors thah could help us to find what is going on. Please post these errors, if they exist.

Comment: I am not very much sure but is there any chance that script is creating HTML element dynamically with same ID and jquery is pointing or trying to disable the elements created during first click on "Add" button... if this is happening then firebug(in mozilla) might show you multiple elements with same ID

Comment: Start with this JSFiddle and change it to demonstrate your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/m3ft9/ You may even solve it yourself there :)

Comment: @ChristosPaisios : this is the error i see after I close the dialog.
#####
too much recursion
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js .... Reload the page to get source for: https://d3b3ehuo35wzeh.cloudfront.net/player/lib/maketutorial_lib_249.js  
Line 6

Comment: @Yogesh: yes, I am trying to create html elements and assign them to the dialog. Yes you are right, in firebug I could see multiple <div id="selector1">. It is being created every time I click on the button which opens the dialog.

Comment: so I think you just need to create element with unique id and then aaply JS functions to that elements so it should behave correctly

Comment: @Yogesh:Thank you. Yes, so it should create the <div id="selector1"> (dialog) only when the button is clicked for the first time. All the open times, it should simply open and close the existing dialog.

Comment: Yes. Call function which creates dialog only if dialog doesn't exists